# GitLab CI fails to connect to remote server

Tags: deployment, gitlab

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, which aims to deploy my master GitLab repository by cloning it to the `test` directory on a specific server.

```
image: ubuntu:latest
before_script:
  - apt-get install -y
  - apt-get update -y
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y && apt-get install git -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null ## /dev/null = trou noir
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - ssh-keyscan charrier.alwaysdata.net >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

deploy:
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -vT user_name@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx "cd test && git clone git@gitlab-myweb.com:repo_group/repo.git"
  only:
    - master
```

The `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is the private key generated when logged in as `user_name` in the `xxx.xx.xxx.xxx`, where I am trying to clone my repo.

Upon running the `ci`, I get this error:

```
user_name@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have clearly messed up the `ssh`, but I am very confused what exactly is my issue.
I was loosely following [this](https://medium.com/p/43bf3cf93775/responses/show) guide.

Can you help me find my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was because I had not done two things:

1. Add the server's public key to the server's authorized keys.
   Inside the server, this is done by simply running this line: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. I had not added the server's public key to the `GitLab` profile's public keys.
   This is done by copying in the contents of `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and pasting them to `https://yourgitlabwebsite.com/profile/keys`

Comment: This was helpful since I ran into similar issue today and the steps helped me in solving the errors.

Comment: Actually, you should config the deployer ssh public key in Settings > Repository > Deploy keys, not on your profile